# GLib atoms and memory chunks

Tags: c, glib, void-pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

The following code snippet is from [The Official GNOME 2 Developer's Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593270305):

```
GMemChunk my_chunk;
my_chunk = g_mem_chunk_new("My Chunk",
                           42,
                           42*16,
                           G_ALLOC_AND_FREE);
gchar *data[50000];
gint i;

/* allocate 40,000 atoms */
for(i = 0; i < 40000; i++)
{
   data[i] = g_mem_chunk_alloc(my_chunk);
}
```

- Does this mean every atom is of 42 bytes, each "memory chunk" contains <s>42</s> 16 atoms, and `40000/16=2500` memory chunks will be created when the above code is run?
- Why are they using gchar* here? Does an implicit cast from gpointer (void*) to gchar* take place when `data[i] = g_mem_chunk_alloc(my_chunk);` is run?
- If the above statement is true then each gchar* points to 42 bytes of memory. How do I access all the bytes of a particular atom, then? Will `data[7]+41` be a usable memory location?

---

- When I try to compile the code gcc produces this error message:

  `error: storage size of ‘my_chunk’ isn’t known`
  What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order of your questions:

- Each memory block contains 16 atoms, but other than that, yes.
- Yes, `void *` can be implicitly converted to any other pointer type in C, and this is typically considered to be good C style.  They are using `gchar *` here because they apparently want to treat each atom as an array of 42 `gchar`s.
- Yes, `data[7][41]` is the last accessible byte of the 8th atom.
- The error is because the declaration of `my_chunk` is wrong (`GMemChunk` is an opaque type that shouldn't be directly instantiated in your code).  The declaration should be:

  `GMemChunk *my_chunk;`

as per the signature of `g_mem_chunk_new()` and `g_mem_chunk_alloc()`.

By the way, the Glib documentation states that the Chunk allocator is deprecated, and you should use the slice allocator instead.